# In my story, a new metal is found, but an overlooked mineral is in the ore of the metal. Why wouldn't prospectors be able to identify it?

Tags: space, mining

The story takes place in the far future. It involves space exploration and inhabiting new planets.

The new overlooked mineral is an "associated mineral" - it occurs where the new metal is found. The new metal (unlike the mineral) is the one that prospectors found valuable.

That new mineral is postulated by an Artificial Intelligence. The humans probably didn't think the ore was valuable or something. What is that something?

In any case, this Artificial Intelligence has figured it out how valuable the overlooked mineral is.

Would it be that they, the prospectors, considered the ore useless or maybe the mineral is too advanced for them to do something useful with it?

What is a reasonable explanation as to why the prospectors either wouldn't notice or discover the new mineral? Or if they discover the new mineral, why they would ignore it?

The concept of an Extended Periodic Table is used. Which includes includes this new mineral.

This mineral is precious because it will go into batteries and it will be more powerful and useful than lithium ion batteries.

Is all of this plausible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: New minerals are found all the time. For a (somewhat famous) example, [davemaoite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davemaoite) was discovered in 2021. (And I really don't understand what you are asking. Could you elaborate a little to make the question clearer?) (Just in case: a [*mineral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral) is a chemical compound which occurs naturally in pure form as a solid. A [*rock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_(geology)) is a solid aggregate of minerals or mineraloids which occurs naturally.)

Comment: Um, I don't really know how to ask this question properly. The thing is I need to find out how "associated minerals" work. In my world a precious metal has been found. I am considering if the ore of this metal could contain something more precious which has been discarded because either nobody thought it was important or they knew it's properties but couldn't do anything about it. How do I edit my question to reflect this? Also I hope I have provided some clarity.

Comment: They ignored the mineral composition of the gold ore because they didn't care. They wanted the gold. If you find gold ore you extract the gold without paying much attention to whatever else is there. It may be found later that you can profitably extract the cobalt or whatever from the leftover tailings. (The problem is that in general the precious metals gold and silver is much more valuable than whatever else is there.)

Comment: The terminology is still a bit confusing, as a "new metal" is an impossibility - all metals are elements, and there's no [space in the table](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/periodic-table/).

Comment: @AlexP thanks that makes sense, I understand now.

Comment: @jdunlop the setting is space exploration in the far future. I talk about an extended periodic table which can include new elements. I hope that's also plausible. I saw the concept somewhere.

Comment: What do you want this mineral to be or do? Precious because it's rare or perhaps has some physical property that nothing else has? Unless we know a bit more about what you're looking for, there's difficulty in finding a specific answer.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane I want the new mineral to go into batteries that are more powerful and useful than the Lithium ion ones.

Comment: OK, great. Could you add these details to the body of the question, as comments tend to not hang around long.

Comment: It's wildly implausible.  The periodic table's numbers are derived from the number of protons in each atom of a an element.  You can certainly have [new transuranic elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transuranium_element), but they are by their nature unstable and you won't find them in naturally-occurring geologic deposits.  If you want to throw out most of chemistry and physics and make this space fantasy, then it could work, but otherwise, if someone reads "new elements" and they're being found as minerals, suspended disbelief is going to be _difficult_.

Comment: @jdunlop: [Island of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability). Good enough for science-fiction.

Comment: @jdunlop Obviously this new metal has 21 and a half protons, so those crazy periodic-table lunatics would never notice it. Their system is just incapable of accepting this new truth. This also explains why the mineral was overlooked.

Comment: Maybe, for reasons of ease, economy, and practicality, the prospectors run a series of crude tests to decide usefulness, rather than the high theory an AI would be expected to do.

Comment: @AlexP The island of stability that means they're stable for nearly twice as many nanoseconds as the rest of the synthetic elements before breaking apart into some other nuclei?

Comment: @JohnO: *"Estimates of the stability of the elements on the island are usually around a half-life of minutes or days; some estimates predict half-lives of millions of years,"* says the repository of all knowledge, without discrimination of quality or truth value. (Which means than in SF you can have stable-stable metals, no questions asked.) We don't really know, because we have no idea how to synthesize them. All the superheavy trans-uranics synthesized in labs have low neutron counts, which make them very very short lived.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbihexium#Nuclear_stability_and_isotopes

> The activity of 5g electrons may influence the chemistry of
> superactinides such as unbihexium in new ways that are difficult to
> predict, as no known elements have electrons in a g orbital in the
> ground state

Unbihexium is element 126, one of the predicted superheavies.  These superheavies will have orbitals no-one has ever observed and the possibility of unusual chemistry.

Your AI understands the 5g orbital.  It predicts that Unbi metal can react with lithium, stabilizing it and immensely augmenting its ability to donate ions to serve as a battery.

Your people have unbi ore but the Unbi / lithium combination was not discovered or observed.  On advice of the AI (which you should name, and make a character!) they synthesize the combination - which is not exactly a salt nor a covalently linked molecule.

Then they play closer attention to some of the AIs other ideas.

Comment: I also recommend that the discoverer of the Unbihexium ore wants it to be named after himself.  Instead, people start calling him Unbi.  He is mad at first but comes to like the nickname.

Comment: Hopefully Unbi does some amazing things to batteries' energy densities, because anything incorporating it is going to be, itself, _extremely heavy_.

Answer (score 0):

May be what you are looking for is an isotope.

Consider (normal) water vs heavy water. Same chemical properties and slightly different physical properties. Nobody ever discovered any difference till we get to a usage (nuclear reactors) where the difference matters.